# Interpolation Banach spaces

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces, interpolation-theory

I am interested in the following. Given are two Banach spaces over $\mathbb{C}^n$ with respective norms $\|\cdot\|_0$ and $\|\cdot\|_1$.

Suppose it holds that

$\tfrac{1}{2}\left(\|x+y\|_0^p + \|x-y\|_0^p\right) \leq \|x\|_0^p + C\|y\|_0^p$

and

$\tfrac{1}{2}\left(\|x+y\|_1 + \|x-y\|_1\right) \leq \|x\|_1 + C\|y\|_1$

Now, I would like to prove that for $\theta \in (0,1)$, we have that

$\tfrac{1}{2}\left(\|x+y\|_\theta^{p_\theta} + \|x-y\|_\theta^{p_\theta}\right) \leq \|x\|_\theta^{p_\theta} + C\|y\|_\theta^{p_\theta}$.

where $\|\cdot\|_\theta$ is the norm obtained by (complex) interpolation between $\|\cdot\|_0$ and $\|\cdot\|_1$. (and $\tfrac{1}{p_\theta} = \tfrac{1-\theta}{p} + \tfrac{\theta}{1}$)

I do believe this inequality ought to follow from Riesz-Thorin. But I do not understand how this inequality follows from the definitions of complex interpolation in this simple setting. In particular, I only understand Riesz-Thorin in the setting of $L_p$ functions since the norms can be represented nicely in terms of products with their duals. Here, the norm $\|\cdot\|_\theta$ is given in terms of $\|\cdot\|_0$ and $\|\cdot\|_1$ which makes it difficult to compare the two expressions.

Any help is much appreciated, I will put a bounty on this once I can.